# exception error with json in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I'm beginner in ios. I developing a call with JSON for access a data and insert after on UITableView. 
In this point on my code

```
    NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer ] deserialize:jsonData error:&error];
```

When compiling I obtained this error

```
2013-02-07 15:49:48.078 comercMobil[12933:c07] +[CJSONScanner scannerWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe7b8
2013-02-07 15:49:48.080 comercMobil[12933:c07] Exception +[CJSONScanner scannerWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe7b8
```

any suggestions? thanks for all

Comment: put you maximum code for mure understanding :)

Comment: I would suggest moving your JSON parsing to Apple's NSJSONSerialization class.  It looks like the library you are using is out of date and deprecated.

Comment: "When compiling I obtained this error" - I didn't know clang used CJSONDeserializer internally...

Comment: That error message is quite specific.  Somewhere you invoked the method `scannerWithData` passing a "this" pointer that was a CJSONScanner object.  And CJSONScanner does not implement `scannerWithData`.  Find out where in your code you're invoking `scannerWithData`.  (And, as others said, this is a runtime error, not a compile error.)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. This is not a compiler error, but rather a runtime error.
2. I don't think this is the line that's causing this error, since you're not calling `scannerWithData` here. I'd search your source for a reference to `scannerWithData`.
3. But, I agree with Sean that you should consider just using [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

   ```
   NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:&error];
   ```

   Or, if you need support for iOS prior to version 5.0, [SBJSON](http://sbjson.org) is very popular.